# Get product of lists of tuples by combining tuple elements?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, tuples, python-itertools

I have a list of tuples that I am trying to get the product of by combining the individual tuple elements.

For example:

```
lists = [
    [(1,), (2,), (3,)],
    [(4,), (5,), (6,)]
]
p = itertools.product(*lists)
for product in p:
    print product
```

This results in a bunch of tuples of tuples:

```
((1,), (4,))
((1,), (5,))
((1,), (6,))
((2,), (4,))
((2,), (5,))
((2,), (6,))
((3,), (4,))
((3,), (5,))
((3,), (6,))
```

What I want is a list of tuples like so:

```
(1,4)
(1,5)
(1,6)
(2,4)
(2,5)
(2,6)
(3,4)
(3,5)
(3,6)
```

**I also need this to hold for any number of initial lists of tuples.**

So in the case of 3:

```
lists = [
    [(1,), (2,), (3,)],
    [(4,), (5,), (6,)],
    [(7,), (8,), (9,)]
]
p = itertools.product(*lists)
for product in p:
    print product
```

I'd like:

```
(1, 4, 7)
(1, 4, 8)
(1, 4, 9)
(1, 5, 7)
(1, 5, 8)
(1, 5, 9)
(1, 6, 7)
(1, 6, 8)
(1, 6, 9)
(2, 4, 7)
(2, 4, 8)
(2, 4, 9)
(2, 5, 7)
(2, 5, 8)
(2, 5, 9)
(2, 6, 7)
(2, 6, 8)
(2, 6, 9)
(3, 4, 7)
(3, 4, 8)
(3, 4, 9)
(3, 5, 7)
(3, 5, 8)
(3, 5, 9)
(3, 6, 7)
(3, 6, 8)
(3, 6, 9)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to flatten the inner tuples, like this

```
for product in p:
    print tuple(itertools.chain.from_iterable(product))
```

For example,

```
>>> from itertools import chain, product
>>> [tuple(chain.from_iterable(prod)) for prod in product(*lists)]
[(1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Comment: does this apply to the n sized list?

Comment: @PyNEwbie Yes, it does.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `map` or `imap` with `sum` or the solution of @thefourtheye to get the desire result

```
from itertools import product, chain, imap
p1 = imap(lambda x:sum(x,tuple()),product(*lists))
p2 = imap(lambda x:tuple(chain.from_iterable(x)),product(*lists))
```

Answer (score 0):

As some of the others mentioned, it's best to flatten the lists first

```
lists = [[x[0] for x in tup] for tup in lists] #flatten
from itertools import product
for p in product(*lists):
    print p
```

That first line with the flatten comment, will convert your lists object to look more like `[ [1,2,3] , [4,5,6]]` and then you can use the itertools product function as before.